# Adding quotes to array values

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to encrypt my raw CSV data to be able to import the generated encrypted CSV into my MySQL database. I have been using MCrypt to encrypt/decrypt all the data.

```
array_push($array, array(Encryption::encrypt($row_content[0]), $row_content[1]);
```

Not encrypted raw_content will be placed between quotes. But the encrypted content will be printed without quotes.

```
lW9Ic8xSo7be0QMThQdMjTgfAw6usjU70eRGJgi,"text"
```

When I try to add quotes to the array like this;

```
array_push($array, array('"'.Encryption::encrypt($row_content[0]).'"', $row_content[1]);
```

I get;

```
"""lW9Ic8xSo7be0QMThQdMjTgfAw6usjU70eRGJgi""","text"
```

Thanks a lot!

Jerome

Comment: You get that *when you do what*?

Comment: Your code might benefit from using some more lines. Your all-in-one statements are a bit hard to read. Did you disable any magic_xxxxx functions in your PHP.ini? Can you dump contents of $row_content just before and after calling Encryption::encrypt?

Comment: Another thing: if you encrypt a string that already contains quotes, the encrypted result will naturally also contain these quotes in it's encrypted contents. If you dont want this, put text without quotes in your variable and add the quotes later on.